# lsp project root

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

I just switched to using lsp for my C++ and Python IDE needs. However, I am running into a constant issue where Python and C++ files have the wrong root, as reported by `(lsp-workspace-root)`.

The root is considered to be the git root (I assume from projectile) which is not the case in my project. When I first opened the file I did not get a prompt asking me for the project root and I made sure to delete the lsp session file (as set in `lsp-session-file`).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want `(lsp-workspace-folders-add)` to add sub-root directories. For example, if your Python files are located in the `tests/` subdirectory, you add it as such with the command. Then, upon starting an LSP server in any of `tests` or `tests/foo` or `tests/bar`, the current working directory will be set to `tests`.

There's also more information at [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/adxcal/subprojects_do_i_need_to_armwrestle_projectile_or/edl7jhl/), quoting:

> > lsp rely on projectile or project.el now only for suggesting project root. Once you open new file in a project and start lsp it will provide several options(import project, blacklist project, select other directory root). Once you select a root it will be persisted and used for the next sessions.
>
> Then there is a command:
>
> > `lsp-workspace-folders-add` - Add workspace folder
>
> Finally under configuration:
>
> > `lsp-session-file` - Automatically guess the project root using projectile/project.

Comment: Good enough. The command `lsp-workspace-folders-add` is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: revisiting, it should recognise emacs project root configured by project-find-functions but doesnt.

Comment: Would it be possible to list added folders into `lsp-workspace`?

Comment: @alper you can see the global list of all folders with `(lsp-session-folders (lsp-session))`. There is also a function `(lsp-workspace-folders)` that supposed to do the same per workspace, however it accepts a parameter which I haven't figured out where to get from.